# Extracting and formatting date from mixed text

Tags: excel, formatting

I'm trying to format a string to display as a date and time in excel.

The string is `6/1/2009 17:55:9`, as you can see it lacks zeros and will not format into a dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss so is unsortable.

After a full day of trying, I have got to the stage where I can output it to look like `01:06:2009  17:55:09` Yet it still won't sort irrespective of what custom format I try. The formula I have come up with to get this output is:

```
=IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(C2, SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),"/",REPT(" ",99)),2*99-98,99)))<10,"0","")&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(C2, SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),"/",REPT(" ",99)),2*99-98,99))&":"&(IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(C2, SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),"/",REPT(" ",99)),1*99-98,99)))<10,"0",""))&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(C2, SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),"/",REPT(" ",99)),1*99-98,99))&":"&(IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(C2, SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),"/",REPT(" ",99)),3*99-98,99)))<10,"0","")&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(C2, SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),"/",REPT(" ",99)),3*99-98,99)))&"  "&(IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),":",REPT(" ",99)),1*99-98,99)))<10,"0","")&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),":",REPT(" ",99)),1*99-98,99)))&":"&IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),":",REPT(" ",99)),2*99-98,99)))<10,"0","")&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),":",REPT(" ",99)),2*99-98,99))&":"&(IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),":",REPT(" ",99)),3*99-98,99)))<10,"0","")&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE((RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-SEARCH(" ",C2,1))),":",REPT(" ",99)),3*99-98,99)))
```

I've absolutely no clue what to do from here, I've tried extracting the value from the cells and sorting that but that doesn't work either.

Anyone have any clue what to do?
Cheers, MS.

EDIT: Thanks to advice from @CallumDA and @elmer007 I now know that the string needed to be converted to a number first, using *1 or =VALUE. I could have applied a sort to the original date in the C column but I wanted it to be presented in the format of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss but some of the values were single digits. To fix this, I searched and extracted each part of the date and time separately and added a zero to the beginning of each if it was only one digit. Doing so made it look like it was in the right format but without the *1 it was still a string and not a number so could not be sorted by date in a chart.

I understand that this is still very confusing as I'm trying to explain all these technical things without understanding any of it in the slightest. Sorry!

Comment: What am I missing? I pasted your string into excel and it formatted as date immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to format a string to display as a date and time in excel.
>   
> ...
>   and will not format into a dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss so is unsortable.

If for some reason your dates are formatted as strings they will only be sortable by `A>Z`. You need to convert the strings to numbers to sort them by time. You can then use custom formatting to give them the `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` you require.

Here are few ways to convert a string to a number:

```
=A1*1
=VALUE(A1)
```

Now your string `6/1/2009 17:55:9` should become `39819.7466319444` (format as `General` to make sure). The integer part represents the date and the decimal part represents the time.

Your dates will be sortable at this point but you can also apply your custom format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:ss:mm` to make them more readable.

Comment: Please refer to the edit. But yes, this worked, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help - thanks for updating the question, it makes sense now :)